# spring-security doesn't work correctly

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to use spring security for authentication and authorization...But I have a problem...The login page does not load correctly!...
I don't know what should I replace "login" ?

```
       http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll();
```

RenderController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class RenderController {


@Autowired
private HRMUserService userService;


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getIndexPage() {
    return "login";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password,
                        @Valid @ModelAttribute("userForm") HRMUser userForm, BindingResult result) {
        return "index";
}
```

This project is single page web application and have two pages:index and login.
It works correctly without authentication and authorization but after adding these functionalities I have problem with loginPage...when I use loginPage("/login") I get this error :

> HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported

When I use .loginPage("/index")

> HTTP Status 404 -

When I use .loginPage("/")
page loads but css and js does not recognized!

Comment: Works as configured... You have a `/login` but that only accepts POST requests... Also why would you want to intercept the request yourself, Spring Security already does that. You only want a GET request which returns the name of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a mapping for the login page with RequestMethod.GET. Something like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getLoginPage() {
    return "login";
}
```

Comment: I added this method but now css and js does not recognized!!